# How would you correctly set up a TypeScript declaration when using "useCallback" for a callback ref?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a React + TypeScript project where I've pulled in the provided "[How can I measure a DOM node?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node)" example, but I don't seem to be able to get React's types to acknowledge a scenario where someone would be passing in the return value of `useCallback` as a `ref`. I've recreated a bare-bones usage of it in [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-rain-w0yw5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). If you open this you should see the TypeScript error indicator on this line:

```js
<div ref={ref} className="App">
```

How exactly should the types be set up to make this valid, or is there something missing in the `@types/react` package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First add `null` to the type of the node inside `useCallback` and add `as const` to the returned array which will type the returned array as a tuple(remember the order of types) instead of making it an array of multiple types

```
function useClientRect() {
  const [rect, setRect] = useState<DOMRect>();

  const ref = useCallback((node: HTMLElement | null) => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setRect(node.getBoundingClientRect());
    }
  }, []);

  return [rect, ref] as const;
}
```

Comment: `as const`! Brilliant. Completely forgot you have to tell TypeScript you're treating an array as a tuple. The additional `null` makes sense too. This got it done. Thank you!

Comment: Great! That saved me! Is there a reason the hook returns a tuple instead of an object with { rect, ref }?

Answer (score 0):

Set returning type for `useClientRect` hook to `[ClientRect | undefined, (node: HTMLDivElement) => void]` and change arguments type for `useCallback` to `HTMLDivElement`:

```
// packages
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";

function useClientRect(): [
  ClientRect | undefined,
  (node: HTMLDivElement) => void
] {
  const [rect, setRect] = useState<ClientRect>();

  const ref = useCallback((node: HTMLDivElement) => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setRect(node.getBoundingClientRect());
    }
  }, []);

  return [rect, ref];
}

export default useClientRect;
```

Comment: I think this does work (and I found another example that did something similar), but I am trying to not have to hard-code in the return values. I think Asaf's suggestion is closer, but thank you for sharing your solution!

Answer (score 0):

In your `use-client-react` you have passed `ClientRect` as a type which doesn't exist. The following works for me fine.

```
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";

function useClientRect() {
  const [rect, setRect] = useState();

  const ref = useCallback((node: HTMLDivElement) => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setRect(node.getBoundingClientRect());
    }
  }, []);

  return [rect, ref];
}

export default useClientRect;
```

Comment: `ClientRect` is what `getBoundingClientRect` returns and is getting stored in `useState`. Removing that type does cause the error to go away, but only because it causes `rect` and `ref` to both become `any`.